# Icons in Select a Rendering Dialog Move When Clicked

Tags: experience-editor

**Sitecore 9.2**:  in the Select a `Rendering dialog` in `Experience Editor`, when a user clicks on the icon for a rendering the other icons around it move about in the dialog.  The selected icon remains selected, but this behavior is disorienting and confuses the users.

Is this a known issue and is there a way to stop this unwanted behavior?

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot describing the behavior?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with Sitecore default theme CSS.

If I remember correctly, the fix was to edit file:

> `/sitecore/shell/themes/standard/default/SelectItemWithThumbnails.css`

and comment `padding` and `border` for `a.scItemThumbnail:hover` and `a.scItemThumbnailSelected` like that:

```
a.scItemThumbnail:hover {
    background-color: #E8F5FD;
    /* border: 1px solid #D8F0FA; */
    /* padding: 4px 11px 4px; */
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.scItemThumbnailSelected {
    background-color: #D5EFFC;
    /* border: 1px solid #99DEFD; */
    /* padding: 4px 11px; */
}
```